# Implementing Switch to toggle Notifications in App Settings

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I'm trying to implemented a Switch in my App's local SettingsVC to toggle Notification On/Off. I've decided for now to leave the user registered with the server (both APNS and AppBoy), and just toggle on/off the local presentation of Notifications.

(That's if the user has registered previously. If they haven't ever registered, this code should register the first time they flip to "on")

Here's my code when the user flips the switch:

```
    func didFlipNotificationSwitch() {

    let isEnabled = isEnabledRemoteNotificationTypes()
    if (isEnabled) {

        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.None], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        } else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.None])
        }
    } else {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Alert, .Badge, .Sound])
        }
    }
    print("isEnabled \(isEnabled)")

}
```

`isEnabledRemoteNotificationTypes()` is a convenience method that checks for registered based on OS - it's works fine. Here it is:

```
 func isEnabledRemoteNotificationTypes() -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let types = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()?.types
        if (types == UIUserNotificationType.None) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    } else {
        let types = UIApplication.sharedApplication().enabledRemoteNotificationTypes()
        if (types == UIRemoteNotificationType.None) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that once registered (`isEnabled` returns `true`) I'm trying to deregister locally by settings types to `.None` as you can see in the method above. This doesn't seem to be working. After the line setting them to `.None` is called, I print out `notificationSettings` in my appDel `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` callback right after setting to `.None`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {

}
```

And get this:

```
Printing description of notificationSettings:
<UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x12684c840; types: (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert UIUserNotificationTypeBadge UIUserNotificationTypeSound);>
```

Why isn't it registering `.None` -OR- Is there a better way to turn off Notification presentation while still maintaining server registration?

Comment: At least for Remote Notifications, there is a function called `unregisterForRemoteNotifications`. For user notifications, I've tried with [.None] and an empty array but the settings were still unchanged, just as you've pointed out - I don't know whether that's possible.

Comment: @peacer212 I threw in `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` and both logged out the types returned from `UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()?.types
` immediately afterwards AND checked the `appDelegate` callback - BOTH showed that the user was still registered.

Comment: I didn't succeed in removing any UIUserNotificationType once they are set. What is the use case?

Comment: @peacer212 I'm implementing a toggle in Settings in-app to turn on/off notifications

Comment: As far as I know once the initial notification types permission grant is made you can't programmatically change it - only the user can. Your app can choose not to use the notification types that it is permitted to use but you can't actually decrease the permissions that you have.

Comment: I also found this http://www.openradar.appspot.com/20781785

Comment: @Paulw11 So basically, I can have a toggle in-app that allows the user to turn notifications on, but if they're already on I can't have them turn off in-app.

Comment: You can't turn them off in the sense that the settings app will show no permissions.  You can turn them off in the sense that you make a decision not to present notifications